# is there any maximum ffmpeg running simultaneously?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, ffmpeg, celery

I'm developing a video encoding service using ffmpeg that wrapped by python+django

My service is running ffmpeg asynchronously by using celery
The problem is, the resulted video sometimes freezing in some part of the video but there's no error raised.

Is there any maximum number that ffmpeg running simultaneously?

Comment: freezing is normal if you're running a lot of ffmpeg processes at the same time and your CPU isn't powerful enough. Try to monitor the CPU usage of your machine.

Comment: There is a practical limit based on your system, especially CPU, but that may not necessarily be your problem. Likely that the more instances you run, the less efficient you are being, especially beyond the count of CPU cores. What exactly are you processing? Why do you need to run multiple instances of ffmpeg?

Comment: @sytech, my encoding workaround as follow: 1. I count the duration, 2. I split the video based-on the duration (e.g. if video 3 mins, then I will split into 10 chunks, it will be 18seconds each chunks) 3. I encode the chunks simultaneously, 4. I merge the encoded chunks into one single video.